# PHP Script being treated as Public in terms of permission

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have a php script that scans my filesystem for text files and minifies them, using my own method of creating a backup (file.txt.bak), minifying the text, then saving the file.

My script is being treated as public though.  Meaning,  unless a file is set to 777 permission,  my script is being denied.   Is there any way around this?

Comment: Find out what user the webservice / php runs on and set groups and / or permissions accordingly

Comment: @PeeHaa 埽 is correct, what is probably happening is you created the file so the owner is your username. My guess is you have this script running on a cron, so when the cron runs it tries to execute the file as admin or some other user other than you so it is denied access.

Comment: Or if a cronjob is not an option, take a look at [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html)